# How do I get my modal to close when a user clicks on the container?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I'm currently studying a full stack course and my modal isn't behaving as expected
I'm a bit lost on what to do as I can't find any documentation anywhere and while clicking on the close button or pressing ESC works, clicking outside of the box doesn't.

The following code is how it has been suggested I approach the issue but, it doesn't work. I've honestly stared at this for about an hour and just can't connect the dots on what is (not) happening? Please excuse all the commenting and additional code as I'm still learning so, it's how I'm able to follow what's going on:

```
function showModal() {
    var $modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
    $modalContainer.classList.add('is-visible');
}

function hideModal() {
    var $modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
    $modalContainer.classList.remove('is-visible');
}

//modal IFFE
document.querySelector('#modal-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    showModal();
});

//-- show modal --
function showModal(title, text) {
    var $modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container'); 
//Selects the element with the associated id

// Clear all content for the selected element
    $modalContainer.innerHTML = '';

    var modal = document.createElement('div'); //creates a div element withing selected element
    modal.classList.add('modal'); //assigns new class to the div element

// Add the new modal content

var closeButtonElement = document.createElement('button'); //creates the close button
    closeButtonElement.classList.add('modal-close'); //assigns a class to the new (close) button
    closeButtonElement.innerHTML = "&times;"; //inserts text within the new(close) button
    closeButtonElement.addEventListener('click', hideModal);

var titleElement = document.createElement('h1');
    titleElement.innerText = title;

var contentElement = document.createElement('p');
    contentElement.innerText = text;

    modal.appendChild(closeButtonElement);
    modal.appendChild(titleElement);
    modal.appendChild(contentElement);
    $modalContainer.appendChild(modal);

    $modalContainer.classList.add('is-visible');
}

document.querySelector('#modal-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    showModal('PokéMon', 'Here is all of the info about your PokéMon');
});

window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    var $modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
        if (e.key === 'Escape' && $modalContainer.classList.contains('is- 
   visible')) {
             hideModal();
    }
});

$modalContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    var target = e.target;
    if (target === $modalContainer) {
        hideModal();
    }
});
```

Expected result: User clicks outside of the modal (on the container) and the modal closed.

Current result: No change in state, modal remains active and visible. Only by clicking on the close button (x) or by pressing ESC is the desired result achievable.

Comment: can you post the html as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was in the incorrect place in the end and should have looked something like this:

```
modal.appendChild(closeButtonElement);
        modal.appendChild(titleElement);
        modal.appendChild(contentImage);
        modal.appendChild(contentHeight);
        modal.appendChild(contentElement);
        $modalContainer.appendChild(modal);

        $modalContainer.classList.add('is-visible');

        $modalContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {                          //listening for an event (click) anywhere on the modalContainer
            var target = e.target;
            console.log(e.target)
            if (target === $modalContainer) {
                hideModal();
            }
        });
    };

    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {                                     //listening for an event (ESC) of the browser window
        var $modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
        if (e.key === 'Escape' && $modalContainer.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
            hideModal();
        }
    });
```

This is because the action was originally being called on page load and targeted within the window instead of being called within the container and being loaded when the modal loads.

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

By Looking at this code I am not sure what is actually supposed to make the modal visible or hide it.  Without access to your css (if you have any).  I am assuming that all you are doing is adding and removing the class `.is-visible` from the `#modal-container` element.

I would suggest that you apply this class to the modal itself, and then you could toggle this class on and off,

Modify your code to do this by doing something like this (added on top of your code):

```
function showModal() {
    var $modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
    $modalContainer.classList.add('is-visible');
    document.querySelector('.modal').classList.remove('hide-el')
}

function hideModal() {
    var $modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
    $modalContainer.classList.remove('is-visible');
    document.querySelector('.modal').classList.add('hide-el')
}
```

Where `hide-el` in your css is:

```
.hide-el {
   display: none;
}
```

You could also modify your code to appply the `is-visible` class to your `modal` element.  You should always try to attach the class/id to the element you want to manipulate if you have that option.

Or if you do not have access to a css file:

```
document.querySelector('.modal').style.display = "none"
```

and

```
 document.querySelector('.modal').style.display = "block"
```

Also, your code seems very verbose, was this boilerplate part of the assignment?
heres a working example: https://codepen.io/mujakovic/pen/zVJRKG

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't aware what code you may have needed. I've created this to help: https://codepen.io/DARKSAV10R/pen/RzYjxm